# Branch.IO showShareSheet not generateting ShortUrl

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-sharesheet

I recently implemented the Branch.IO framework in iOS project. Everything is working but while calling "**showShareSheet(with: blp, andShareText: shareTxt + "\n\n", from: vc, completionWithError: callback)**"  its opening the Ios Share Sheet option, while selecting installed shareable app, branch method returning long URL not short URL.

Details:-

Branch.IO version :- 0.24.1

Swift Version:- 3

Sample output:- "https://ghhh.app.link/?%24identity_id=528124114238637064&channel=Email&feature=Share%20Post&type=0&duration=0&source=ios&data=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"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Branch iOS and Android SDKs default to generating long links when there is no internet connectivity or in an event of a patchy network. But they do generate short links when internet connectivity is available and Branch servers are reachable.

Comment: But I am getting the issue always. Any suggestions